# Laravel - GET request download logout automaticlly

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-5.7

i have a download file link like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('download_document', ['file' => 'agos.pdf']) }}" class=" text-info" style="cursor: pointer;">Download file</a>
```

**ROUTES**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth','Admin','active'], 'prefix' => 'admin'], function(){

    // USERS
    Route::resource('user','UserController');
    Route::post('user/permissions/update','UserController@update_permission')->name('update_user_permissions');

    // MODULI
    Route::resource('module','ModuleController');

    // MODULISITICA
    Route::resource('modulistica','ModulisticaController');

Route::post('modulistica_cliente','ModulisticaController@update_client_module')->name('modulistica_post_cliente');
    Route::post('modulistica_prodotto','ModulisticaController@update_product_module')->name('modulistica_post_prodotto');
    Route::get('modulistica/download/cliente/{file}','ModulisticaController@download_cliente')->name('modulistica_download_cliente');
    Route::get('modulistica/download/{file}','ModulisticaController@download_module')->name('modulistica_download_module');
    Route::get('modulistica/download/prodotto/{file}','ModulisticaController@download_prodotto')->name('modulistica_download_prodotto');

    // UTILITY
    Route::post('utility/become/client','UtilityController@become_client')->name('utility_become_client');
    Route::resource('loan','LoanController');
    Route::get('area_download/document/{file}', function ($file){

        $path_file = storage_path().'/app/public/documents/'.$file;
        return response()->download($path_file, $file);

    })->name('download_document');

});
```

**ERROR**

Arrival at the "https://mysite.it/admin/loan" view without problems. When I click on the GET link it redirects me to the LOGIN, but being my user logged in by login redirects me to "https://mysite.it/home".

I did some tests getting the following information:

- Request does not arrive at route "area_download / document / {file}"
- The request does not arrive at the 'Admin', 'active' middlewares.

So my conclusions are that the problem is in the middleware "**Web**" or "**Auth**" but I can not understand why. Place the entire group of routes, if it can be useful. If you need more on the routes, I can attach screenshots!

I would appreciate your help thank you!

Comment: have you done some tests without "Admin", "active" middlewares?

Comment: remove web..it is unnecessary, it automatically applied to all web routes

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din yes i tried, same error

Answer (score 1):

If you just allow downloading a file without any authentication then,
You can try this :

**Blade File**

```
<a href="{{ Storage::url($file_name) }}" download class=" text-info" style="cursor: pointer;">Download file</a>
```

From this user can directly download the file. Just need to add file path in `href` and `download` attribute.

or else remove the middleware `AUTH` if you don't want to Authenticate the user.

---

And you want to authenticate the user then need `route:list` and `middleware` details.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! the problem was that my get request was made this way.

https://mysite.it/admin/area_download/document/example.pdf

the final PDF extension creates system error. Avoiding the final extension such as:

https://mysite.it/admin/area_download/document/example.pdf/go

Problem solved!

Comment: This solution saved my life. I know it's 4 years ago but thanks!